# WP Multisite, I cannot reach the default domain, by domain name or by IP address

Tags: wordpress, bitnami

I am having an issue with WP Multisite certified by Bitnami. I am following the Configuration [1] section and have just run bnconfig to set the default domain. When I try to get a browser to that domain, it fails to load.

When I go by IP address, for instance going through the GCP Deployment Manager for my instance displays IP Address links for the default blog and default blog /wp-admin. Neither are reachable. I am testing the configuration prior to adding subdomains. I do not understand why this is so. I have tried searching for a solution, but can't find one that addresses this issue.

I am reinstalling and will note every step...

1. create new GCP project
2. Launch the deploy of the 'WordPress Multisite certified by Bitnami and Automattic'.
3. Edit the instance and set the n1-standard-2 arch.
4. Switch the IP from ephemeral to static.
5. In Deployment Manager with my new instance,
6. see WP Multisite info to right, including user/passwd.
7. Open the blog by ip address.
8. Open the admin by ip address. Login with user/passwd.
9. In admin activate Jetpack. Connect.
10. In Namecheap, update all domains with new IP Address, in the A records. [2][3]
11. Skip config SMTP. Skip disabling cron.
12. ***At Configure WordPress Multisite*** [1]
13. Site's Siteurl & Home are both http://35.227.14.44.xip.io
14. Config my master domain with:
15. > sudo bnconfig --machine_hostname churchofthesacrifice.org
16. move script to .disabled
17. ctl restart all services> sudo ctlscript.sh restart
18. `Was happening, no more: 18. site/admin UNREACHABLE by IP address: http://35.227.14.44/ AND domain name: http://churchofthesacrifice.org/`
19. Going by IP: http://35.227.14.44 or http://35.227.14.44/qp-admin, it gives a site `Registration has been disabled.`: but the VetsforWeed link/description is there.
20. When I click the link, going to the root http://vetsforweed.net, it gives this error: `The
     page isn’t redirecting properly`.

The answer is remove URL Redirect records.

---

[1] Configure WordPress Multisite - https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/wordpress-multisite/configuration/configure-wordpress-multisite/

[2] Repaired, removing URL Redirect records, DNS records for churchofthesacrifice.org  primary domain

- `A Record @    35.227.14.44 Automatic`
- `CNAME Record   www   churchofthesacrifice.org. 30 min`
- `CNAME Record   callistohouse   churchofthesacrifice.org. Automatic`
- `CNAME Record   institute   churchofthesacrifice.org. Automatic`
- `CNAME Record   vetsforweed   churchofthesacrifice.org. Automatic`
- `CNAME Record   parish_militia   churchofthesacrifice.org. Automatic`

[3] Repaired, removing URL Redirect records, DNS records for vetsforweed.net subdomain-mask domain.

- `CNAME Record    www vetsforweed.net. Automatic`
- `A Record    @  35.227.14.44  Automatic`

Comment: You will need to provide more information about the failure. What error you get when accessing the site? Is there any error in the Apache's log (/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/error_log)? I can access your domain properly churchofthesacrifice.org, however I can see that the domain is not pointing directly to the instance's IP, there is a CDN or something similar in front of it. https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/churchofthesacrifice.org

Comment: No error, when I click the top link in Redirect Notice page, the Redirect Notice page remains. I open link in new tab and nothing, totally blank. In apache's error_log https://pastebin.com/jUnXPYxM *twice with SIGTERM, then twice without.* I do not understand how the [domain is not pointing directly to the instance's IP]. Could this be a DNS issue? I added 5 CNAMEs {_*one per subdomain <corporate, callistohouse, vetsforweed>, a www and a wildcard *} and a URL Redirect and an A record for the IP.

Comment: Note I did the troubleshooting steps and everything looks good.

Comment: I was able to get to the site and the wp-admin, for a time. I was loading the Civist plugin and then it started going wonky again, with a `The
 page isn’t redirecting properly`. It is translating the IP address, to go to the blog with the domain name: `http://churchofthesacrifice.org`, but the error loading occurs. Why is it working one minute then hiding again the next? It seems very unreliable, and my DNS records must be right to get to the site at the beginning of this comment.

Comment: In using https://centralops.net/co/NsLookup.aspx, I find that churchofthesacrifice.org reports 2 A records, but I only see one in my Namecheap DNS records list. 1) `churchofthesacrifice.org IN A 192.64.119.254 1800s (00:30:00)`, 2) `churchofthesacrifice.org IN A 35.227.14.44 1799s (00:29:59)`

I do not see any A record for the first A record, just the second.

Comment: 1 IP is correct and 1 is old. My `callistohouse.club` reports only 1 A record and the IP is correct. I have not yet setup subdomains in my WordPress network config.

Comment: The support person with Namecheap is telling me to delete the URL Redirect records, which I have done so. Waiting for propagation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woot! All 4 of my blogs are operational and I am able to login to all. I found this article about the login problem with cookies.

[Disable WP cookies](https://help.servmask.com/knowledgebase/error-cookies-are-blocked-or-not-supported-by-your-browser-you-must-enable-cookies-to-use-wordpress/)

I am totally psyched!

Now I just need to import a non-multisite WP Migration file (.wpress), not .WXR that the WordPress Importer plugin was trying to import, which failed. So I really need to shell out $228!? Dang! I have a 163MB .wpress file.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the URL Redirect records from all domains. My main site is now appearing, as is /wp-admin. I believe I am good.

I will fix the original post with the correct DNS records, that it may help the next.